# my simple rng code is not working. Why is that so?

Tags: javascript, math, random, while-loop

I'm new to Javascript, as of right now I just watched a 3 hour-long tutorial and took part in a few private programming lessons. I was assigned my first project where I try to simulate a battle between two armies. Here is the code.

```
var myArmy = ["arcieri", "fanteria", "cavalleria", "morale"]  // <--- my Army brigades
function rng_loop() {
Math.floor(Math.random * myArmy.length)  // <---- the rng function
}

while (myArmyStrength > 0 && enemyArmyStrength > 0) {
  rng_loop()
} if (rng_loop() > 1) {
  enemyArmyStrength - 25
} else if (rng_loop() < 1) {
myArmyStrength - 20
}

/* this is what was supposed to be my loop generating random numbers and killing off both armies based on the value of said random numbers until one of the two armies got to 0. myArmyStrength and enemyArmyStrength were specified earlier on. */

if (myArmyStrength > 0 && enemyArmyStrength <= 0) {
console.log("we won the battle! Roma invicta!")
} else if (myArmyStrength <= 0 && enemyArmyStrength > 0) {
console.log("We lost the battle...")
} 
/* this if else statement was supposed to console.log a message either announcing a victory or defeat to the enemy army, but it's not console.logging anything. Why is that so? */
```

Comment: `rng_loop` is missing a return statement

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you do not return a value from `nrg_loop()`.  use `return Math.floor(....` in that function body.

Comment: Also `Math.random()` is a method.  You have to use `()` to invoke it

Answer (score 0):

### Four problems

#### 1. Your function needs to return something

Currently you are calculating something and throwing the result away. What you must do is `return` the result. Also, as pointed out by a commenter above, you need `()` after the `Math.random`, because you want the function `Math.random` to be executed.

```
function rng_loop() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * myArmy.length) 
}
```

#### 2. Don't call the function 3 times per loop: call it just once, and store the value

I have called it `fightOutcome` in the code below. If you don't store it like this, each time you call the rng_loop() function, it will return a different number. The first one will be thrown away, and more importantly the second two calls (for ">1" and "<1") will be not coordinated, i.e you could trigger both the first *and* the second! Or neither.

#### 3. The code in the { } of the 'while' needs to include all the 'ifs'

```
while (myArmyStrength > 0 && enemyArmyStrength > 0) {
    const fightOutcome = rng_loop()
    if (fightOutcome > 1) {
      enemyArmyStrength -= 25
    } else if (fightOutcome < 1) {
      myArmyStrength -= 20
    }
}
```

#### 4. You've mis-spelled `-=` as just `-`

You were attempting to reduce the two armyStrength variables using

```
enemyArmyStrength -= 25;
```

But unfortunately you wrote just

```
enemyArmyStrength - 25
```

What that did was just calculate your enemyArmyStrength - 25, and then throw the result away, rather than write it into the enemyArmyStrength variable.

#### Bonus suggestion: don't separately test 1 etc

Two problems with that. First, the very rare possibility that the value is *exactly* 1. Extremely unlikely here but will matter more when you write other types of code for ">" and "not >". The correct way is for one to be "<1" and the other ">=1". (Or you could move the `=` to the `<` side).

Second, it is easy to make a mistake. (Which you have done, in fact!)

My suggestion is to only test one half of the question, and use `else` to take care of the alternative possibility.

```
 if (fightOutcome > 1) {
  enemyArmyStrength - 25
} else {
  myArmyStrength - 20
}
```

Your followup question
`Sorry to bother you, I applied the modifications suggested by you but sadly the console still doesn't log any results. Any idea why?`

I've explained the fourth bug too now, sorry.

```js
let myArmyStrength = 20;
let enemyArmyStrength = 30;

var myArmy = ["arcieri", "fanteria", "cavalleria", "morale"]

function rng_loop() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * myArmy.length) 
}

while (myArmyStrength > 0 && enemyArmyStrength > 0) {
  if (rng_loop() > 1) {
    enemyArmyStrength -= 25
  } else {
    myArmyStrength -= 20
  }
}

if (enemyArmyStrength <= 0) {
  console.log("we won the battle! Roma invicta!")
} else  {
  console.log("We lost the battle...")
}
```

If you run that snipped above, it now works.